# What exactly do the well taps in MOSFETs do and how?

Tags: mosfet, integrated-circuit, cmos, semiconductors, vlsi

Do they affect the flow of charge carriers or charge concentrations at all in the device? How so? Up to this point I've tried to visualize the effects that the various doped areas had on device operation (w.r.t. how the charge carriers are affected) but I'm having a little difficulty doing so with the well taps. How do they affect the movement of charge during device operation? Do they redirect/divert current somehow?

I'm also a bit confused as to what their main function is, as I've read both that they're used mainly to a) prevent latch-up and b) lower the resistance of the wells. For each of these functions, how is this achieved? That is, what exactly are the mechanisms by which the well taps provide said functions?

Answer (score 1):

Well taps, if placed densely enough to quickly provide charges into the well and thus maintain the well at either Ground or VDD, allow a fast and clean switching of the FET's channel conductivity. This clean switching gives low gate/FF delays and low edge jitter.

I've seen place-and-route cell-libraries that DID NOT HAVE A WELL TAP in each cell; in fact, the library/rules allowed up to 30 (THIRTY) cells between Well Taps (also called Well Ties). Clearly the new-graduates and the SENIOR_LIBRARY_DEVELOPER had a learning experience just ahead.

I later heard that library caused lots of SHMOO problems, lots of delays in logic state changes (surprise), and the library had to be redone by adding Well Taps/Ties into each cell.

WARNING --- substrate ties/taps have the SAME function and behavior and responsibility.

WARNING#2 --- ignore well taps, and end up with massive interactions between the various logic activities, massive crosstalk on switching, massive ISI InterSymbolInterference, and horrid Deterministic Jitter.